# How to go around roots when trying to figure out if a sequence has a limit and if it converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider this sequence

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^5 + 3n^2}$$

Now what I did is i tried to get rid of the root by transforming it into an exponent meaning;

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n^5 + 3n^2)^n$$

Now I've multiplied n into the paranthesis and I have this
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^6 + 3n^3$$

And since n is moving to infinity,the numbers will be increasing infinitly so the limit is simply $$
 \infty$$

Now since I have no way to prove that this is the correct solution,and on a few similar problems,where I was able to check my work(they also had to deal with roots) I've made a mistake on most of them. Now I'd like if anyone has a tip or some "trick" on how to deal with roots when it comes to these type of problems?

Thank you!

Comment: You really need to learn something about exponents.  Both of your steps are wrong.  For the first, $\sqrt[n]{x} = x^{1/n}$, not $x^n$.  For the second, a power is not a product.

Comment: Oh yea you are right its not x^n but x^1/n,that was my bad. But for the second I thought I could apply the rule  $$ (a^n)^m = a^{n*m} $$

Comment: One way would be to sandwich the sequence. For all large enough $n$ we have
$$n^5\le n^5+3n^2\le 2n^5.$$ Then use the limits of $2^{1/n}$ and $n^{1/n}$.

Comment: You didn't apply the rule $(a^n)^m = a^{nm}$, you applied $(a^n)^m = m a^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^5 + 3n^2}=\lim_{n \to \infty} (n^5+3n^2)^{1/n}$$
Now consider
$$\log L = \log \lim_{n \to \infty} (n^5+3n^2)^{1/n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \log(n^5+3n^2)^{1/n}=$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log(n^5+3n^2)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log(n^5+3n^2)}{n}=$$
That is an indetermination form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Apply L'hopital rule
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{5n^4+6n}{n^5+3n^2}=0$$
As $\log L =0$ we can conclude that $L=1$

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it now